# PHP preg_match_all is not working when into function

Tags: php, function, preg-match-all

There's a set of code I've used for a while to find strings into a file. But when I put it into a function, I don't get results and I think that it's `preg_match_all` that is not working. I don't know how to get this fixed.

Here's my code (copy/pasted from a tutorial):

```
function getprice($keyword, $outputvar) {
    $pattern = preg_quote($keyword, '/');
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
    echo "pattern:" . $pattern;
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
        $str=implode("\n", $matches[0]);
        $str = substr( $str, ( $pos = strpos( $str, ':' ) ) === false ? 0 : $pos + 1 );
        $$outputvar = $str;
    }
    else {
        $$outputvar = "99999";
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using the function?  You don't return anything and `$$outputvar` is only available in the function.

Comment: What's the URL of the tutorial?

Comment: @Barmar I found the tutorial 2 years ago, I can't say where. I've been using it since. But now I want to run it as a function.

Comment: I thought you got the `$$outputvar` part from the tutorial, that's what I wanted to see.

Comment: Where do you set `$contents`?

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled, with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Then you would have seen the warning about the undefined variable `$contents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do with `$outputvar` and `$$outputvar`, but don't use them.  `return` something.  Also, `$contents` needs to be passed in:

```
function getprice($keyword, $contents) {
    $pattern = preg_quote($keyword, '/');
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
        $str = implode("\n", $matches[0]);
        $str = substr( $str, ( $pos = strpos( $str, ':' ) ) === false ? 0 : $pos + 1 );
        return $str;
    }
    else {
        return "99999";
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
$outputvar = getprice($some_keyword, $some_contents);
```

This only addresses the use of the function, not your regex or the data that is parsed, as you haven't posted any test cases.

Comment: Thanks for answering quickly,
I didn't posted test because the code works perfectly when not inside a function. 
The $$outputvar was because de second parameter of the function was the name of the variable into which to put the result.
I tried your alternative and now I always get "99999". This means that the condition preg_match_all is false even if it shoud not be.

I trying to be as clear as I can

Comment: @user3464563 You're never setting `$contents`. It should be another parameter to the function. As a result, you're matching the regexp against an empty string, so of course it fails.

Comment: @Barmar WONDERFUL!!! That did the job! `$content` was declared outside of the function and I didn't thought it would be null once in the function. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why didn't you think it would be null? This is a normal PHP variable scope issue. You have to pass it as a parameter or use a `global` declaration in the function.

Comment: @Barmar Well because I'm a beginner and I don't know much of PHP. I get my scripts working with tutorials and examples found on stackoverflow.